# Getting error:02016002:system library:stat:No such file or directory on shared hosting plan

Tags: node.js, firebase

I have a Node.js app on a shared hosting plan. I found out that when I login using the Firebase Authentication layer, I get a 401 error. While digging deeper, I found the following error message on the server:

```
Error: error:02016002:system library:stat:No such file or directory
at Sign.sign (internal/crypto/sig.js:103:29)
at Object.sign (/home/cp1183833p05/nodevenv/node-app/12/lib/node_modules/jsonwebtoken/node_modules/jwa/index.js:152:45)
at Object.jwsSign [as sign] (/home/cp1183833p05/nodevenv/node-app/12/lib/node_modules/jsonwebtoken/node_modules/jws/lib/sign-stream.js:32:24)
at Object.module.exports [as sign] (/home/cp1183833p05/nodevenv/node-app/12/lib/node_modules/jsonwebtoken/sign.js:204:16)
at ServiceAccountCredential.createAuthJwt_ (/home/cp1183833p05/nodevenv/node-app/12/lib/node_modules/firebase-admin/lib/auth/credential.js:103:20)
at ServiceAccountCredential.getAccessToken (/home/cp1183833p05/nodevenv/node-app/12/lib/node_modules/firebase-admin/lib/auth/credential.js:76:26)
at FirebaseAppInternals.getToken (/home/cp1183833p05/nodevenv/node-app/12/lib/node_modules/firebase-admin/lib/firebase-app.js:65:73)
at AuthorizedHttpClient.send (/home/cp1183833p05/nodevenv/node-app/12/lib/node_modules/firebase-admin/lib/utils/api-request.js:666:34)
at /home/cp1183833p05/nodevenv/node-app/12/lib/node_modules/firebase-admin/lib/auth/auth-api-request.js:1472:37
at processTicksAndRejections (internal/process/task_queues.js:97:5) {
opensslErrorStack: [
'error:0E07606D:configuration file routines:module_run:module initialization error',
'error:0E07B075:configuration file routines:ssl_module_init:ssl command section empty'
],
library: 'system library',
function: 'stat',
reason: 'No such file or directory',
code: 'ERR_OSSL_SYS_NO_SUCH_FILE_OR_DIRECTORY'
}
```

This error happens only when I restart the app and I sign in for the first time. Then, it happens at random occasion. How can I fix this?

NodeJS version 12.18.3

Answer (score 0):

I contacted the hosting provider and found that the issues were tied to jsonwebtoken and firebase-admin packages.

Comment: Did you ever find a solution for this?  I'm struggling with the same problem..

Comment: I opted to remove Firebase Authentication from my app.

Comment: Hmm..  Not an option, unfortunately.  But thanks for the input.

Comment: are you using namecheap shared hosting? I ran into the same problem

Comment: after lots of googling, by downgrade node to version 10, problem solved